# Django: CSRF verification fail despite token being provided

Tags: html, jquery, django, ajax

I get 403 error due to csrf_token verification failure in spite of token explicit declaration in an ajax call. I for my data dictionary in the same manner in other functions and it works just great.

**Here is JS:**

```
$(document).on("click", ".update-cleaning", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var input_field_name = $(this).attr('name')
  var obj_id = $(this).attr('value')
  var model_name = $(this).attr('data-model')
  var field_name = $(this).attr('data-field')
  var value = $("#" + input_field_name + obj_id).val();
  if (!value) {
      alert('Fill the field!')
    }
  else {
  $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'ajax_update_cleaning' %}",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'object_id': obj_id, 'model_name': model_name, 'field_name': field_name, 'value': value, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .done(function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                })
        }
});
```

**My html form is in a popover which is toggled by a click on `<td>` and looks like this:**

```
<td class="text-md-center with-popover" name="frequency" value="{{cleaning.id}}">
    {{ cleaning.frequency }}
    <div id="frequency{{cleaning.id}}" style="display: none">
    <form method="POST">
    <label for="cleaning_frequency">Frequency: </label>
    <input id="cleaning_frequency{{cleaning.id}}" type="number" name="cleaning" value="{{cleaning.frequency}}"> 
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm update-cleaning" name="cleaning_frequency" data-model="Cleaning" data-field="frequency" value="{{cleaning.id}}"> Change </button>
    </form>
  </div>
</td>
```

Could you give me some ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In any template that uses a POST form, use the csrf_token tag inside the  element if the form is for an internal URL, e.g.:

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
```

Read more in the [Django  Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/)